# How to do this triangular arc warp text in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text-wrap

How to do this arc text in Photoshop?
I've tried using arc. but it's a circular. I don't know how to do it in angle like in the picture

[image: ARC TEXT]

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that a vector-based application was used to create the artwork in your image. Photoshop *can* be used though. It all really depends upon desired final output. Photoshop doesn't output vector files. That may not be of any consequence for your use though.

In either Photoshop or a most other applications, you would need to **create shapes** from type (`Type > Convert to Shape`), then *manually* move paths and anchors using the **Direct Selection Tool** (White Arrow).

Very crude example animation....

[image]

There is no filter or effect which will add a hard angle to the bottom of text.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using a **Shape Builder tool** and **Envelope Distort** combination with the outlined text, a die cut shape and the character envelope shapes:

[image]

---

**Shape Builder Tool** + <kbd>Alt</kbd> between P, R, I, I, T, I and the *Die Shape*

[image: Shape Builder Tool]

---

**Envelope Distort** between M, V, E and the corresponding *Envelope Shapes*. Select the character and the shape and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> Win

[image: Envelope]

Comment: ermm.. Photoshop `:)`.. but I agree if it were Illustrator `:)`

Comment: yeap, I did't see the tag